# Dynamic reload configured Cassandra TLS key materials

Tags: ssl, cassandra

I have Cassandra cluster where I already configured paths to keystore and truststore.
In case I reissued keystore and truststore - I need to restart Cassandra service on each node.

My question is - if it is possible to dynamically reload these key materials without need to restart the nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the Cassandra version. Starting with Cassandra 4 it can [automatically reload trust & key stores](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/operating/security.html#ssl-certificate-hot-reloading), or you can force reload with `nodetool reloadssl`.

In earlier versions you need to do rolling restart of the cluster.